# How to Fix Checkmarx Stored XSS issue from a getResultList element

Tags: java, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding

In Java, in the line below:

```
TypedQuery<T> query=entityManger.createQuery(queryString, clazz);

List<T> result =query.getResultList();
```

It is saying that the variable result needs to be properly filtered or encoded otherwise it may enable a Cross-Site Scripting Attack.

I have already used `HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(queryString)` String object.

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to encode the `output`, not the `queryString`. See @RomanCanlas result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkmarx will ultimately look at the sink(output). You will have to then perform htmlEscape in each of the resulting item in the List

```
List<T> newResult = new ArrayList<T>();
for (T temp : result) {
    newResult.add(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape((String) temp));
}
```

Comment: you are welcome @nitesh and welcome to stackoverflow!